# decltype(auto) foo() returns local reference without any warning

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

While playing with examples from Modern C++ I've written the following code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static int count = 0;

class Counter
{
public:
    Counter() { ++count; };
    Counter(Counter& r) { ++count; };
    Counter(Counter&& r) { ++count; };
    ~Counter() { --count; };

    void foo() {};
};

decltype(auto) foo_warn()
{
    Counter c;
    return (c);             // Warning about returning local reference
}

decltype(auto) foo_no_warn()
{
    Counter c;
    return 1==1 ? c : c;    // No warning, still local reference returned
}

int main()
{
    Counter& a = foo_warn();
    Counter& b = foo_no_warn();

    std::cout << count << std::endl;  // prints 0

    a.foo();
    b.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Code compiled with command:

`g++-6 -std=c++14 -Wall -O0    decl_fail.cpp   -o decl_fail`

Output:

```
g++-6 -std=c++14 -Wall -O0    decl_fail.cpp   -o decl_fail
decl_fail.cpp: In function ‘decltype(auto) foo_warn()’:
decl_fail.cpp:19:10: warning: reference to local variable ‘a’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  Counter a;
          ^
```

It's clear for me that `decltype(auto)` returns the reference for expressions (but still not intuitive), therefore `a` and `b` are invalid references (proven by `count==0`).

The question is why compiler didn't warn me about that in `foo_no_warn`?

Did I just found a bug in compiler or this is some explainable behaviour?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. clang and gcc up to and including 5 report this warning.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius return (c) does indeed return a reference.

Comment: you can check several compiler version for this here: http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @Hayt thanks for the link! Indeed it looks like gcc 6.1 introduced this bug.

Comment: @woockashek 6.2 seems to work instead.

Comment: On my compiler, both gcc and clang gives warning on both functions.

Comment: @skypjack no it doesn't, still produces only one warning - there sould be two.

Is there any person allowed to file a bug in gcc bugzilla? It looks like creating accounts on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla is restricted.

Comment: @woockashek [It produces two warnings indeed](https://godbolt.org/g/z91SFq).

Comment: @skypjack only from O2+ - probably just because it removes unneed 1==1 compatition

Comment: @woockashek Oh, interesting, I didn't notice it. Well, more information to be added to the issue you are opening, right? :-)

Comment: @skypjack I've tried but I coudn't create account on their bugzilla.

Comment: @woockashek I can fill a bug for you and mention the question on SO if you want. I'm not looking for credits anyway, so I'd suggest you to try once more to create an account. At your disposal.

Comment: @skypjack feel free to submit this bug. Link to this topic is more than enough :)

Comment: @woockashek [That's it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77591).

Comment: @woockashek unrelated to the warnings or the bug, `Counter(Counter& r)` is a fairly useless copy constructor. It should be `Counter(const Counter& r)`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for having fixed the issue on the bugzilla. Actually I missed a few details, I'm sorry.

Comment: `decltype((c))` returns `C&` but `decltype(c)` returns `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's state that the problem isn't related explicitly with decltype(auto) since you would get pretty much the same result if the function returned Counter& explicitly.

You could consider the following code:

```
typedef std::vector<int> Type;

class DataContainer {
public:
    DataContainer() : data(Type(1024, 0)) {}
    const Type& getData() const { return data; }

private:
    const Type data;
};

const Type& returnLocalRef()
{
    DataContainer container;
    const Type& data = container.getData();
    return data; // o! returning a ref to local - no warning for most compilers
}
```

Although a local reference is returned the compiler doesn't give a warning neither in VS2015 nor gcc48 (with -Wall). However if you removed the reference from **const Type& data** the compiler would catch the problem right away. Should you consider such behaviour an error? Debatable.

Compier basic job is to compile the code. It warns the developer about some obvious issues but in most cases it won't do any deeper analysis of the program logic (compilation time would suffer).
This is what code static analysis tools are developed and should be used for.

The described case can be considered a simple example but a single level of indirection is enough to "fool" the compiler. Since to verify this the compiler would need to check what is actually returned from the getData method.

Making a simple modification:

```
Type globalData;
...
const Type& getData() const { return globalData; }
```

would make the reference returned from the returnLocalRef function valid.
Hence, this can be considered a tradeoff for the compiler between analysis complexity and time efficiency.